# I need to test if I have registered for push notification correctly and I receive remote notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios-simulator

I need to test if device token is received properly (if registration is successful), notification is received and badge count is updated in simulator. I know that we cant use push notification from simulator and check if badge count is updated from simulator. But my question is, will I be able to test by connecting with my device and debug from Xcode. Or Is there any other way to check before giving a beta test.

I have got the development and distribution (ad hoc) provisioning profiles.
I checked if push notification is enable in these profiles.

I use development to debug from simulator using device.

I followed all the steps required to set push notification from app side.

Is there a way to send notification manually and check if its received properly. Since the changes in the server are not yet completed I need to check it from app side.

Somebody please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm recommeding you reading this 2-part tutorial from ray wenderlich: [Apple Push Notification Services in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect your device and debug from Xcode. You'll be able do see if the registration to APNS succeeded or failed based on the callback method being called (either the one that returns the device token or the one that indicates an error).

However, you can't send a notification without the server side. Well, technically you can, but it will be as complicated as implementing the push at the server side (you'll have to establish a TLS connection with APN server and send a notification in the binary format that Apple expects), and probably more complicated, since you'll have to implement it in Objective C.

Comment: ok thank you. So if I connect device and debug, I get device token displayed in didRegisterWithDeviceToken: method, which means registration is successful.

Comment: To test push notifciation with development push certificate can we debug from simulator using device or should we need to give ad hoc build and only check